# DIV Column Resizing

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to create a 3 column DIV that allows me to resize the div column widths by drag handles using Jquery.  This JSFiddle may better explain it. http://jsfiddle.net/SHEDz/1/

Ideally I want to be able to drag the div.bar left or right and the divs to the left or right of the bar resize accordingly so that it doesnt exceed the total width.

Ive seen an exmaple like this http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php but my Jquery writing isnt getting me what Im after.

anyone out there up to the challenge?

Comment: Out of curiosity, that link showing what you are after, the splitter code he made is open course for use. (He has a GNU License in the code) Why not just use it? If you want to figure out how to make it yourself from scratch, I understand, but if you don't need to, why not use it?

Comment: HI Drahkar, Thakyou for your reply.  I have struggled to get a simple 3 column layout using his code.   I can get a 2 column working but a 3 column even though his exampkle looks to have 3 columns doesnt seem straight forward to code up.

Comment: If you've tried something and it didn't work you're better off posting that and asking for help figuring out where you went wrong, rather than asking somebody to just go ahead and write the code for you.

Comment: trust me I wasn;t trying to get someone to write the code for me, just some pointers would have been great. The spliiter function is cool but it doesnt work quite how I need it to.  However with much persistence I've managed to get to this: http://jsfiddle.net/SHEDz/6/  which ain't bad for a first attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the jQuery Layout container plugin:

http://jsbin.com/ucaxu4/3

Comment: thank you Steve, Ive tried to get the Jquery Layout container to do what I want and isnt right.  However Im having some luck building the thing myself from scratch.  as soon as Im done I'll post my solution here.

Answer (score -1):

Ive still got a few things I need to do to the final version however this is ideally what I was after and its turned out better than expected: http://www.arondraper.co.uk/divColumns.php

Comment: The link isn't working anymore. Please, consider putting your solution on jsfiddle if you think it's still worth to share?